# Javascript to strip html and currency symbol

Tags: javascript

I have this html:

```
<span class="price-amount amount"><span class="price-currencySymbol">£</span>49.99</span>
```

I want to extract just the value of '49.99' without the html and currency symbol.

I have tried this:

```
function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('.price-amount');
    var price = element.innerHTML.replace('£', '');
    return price;
}
```

But the result is this:

```
 <span class="price-currencySymbol">£</span>49.99
```

Rather than: 49.99

Comment: You could use a regular expression like `\d+\.\d+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var price = element.innerHTML.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
```

where

`.match` searches the pattern of price using regex.

`[0]` returns the first match, and in your case it would be the only match.

Answer (score 0):

By using selector logic and accessing the proper text node you don't even need to use regexp.

```js
var price = document.querySelector(".price-amount")
                    .childNodes[1].textContent;
console.log(`Extracted price: ${price}`);
```

```html
<span class="price-amount amount"><span class="price-currencySymbol">£</span>49.99</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete what's in the `'.price-currencySymbol'` span in every case, you juste have to empty its html:

```
document.querySelector(".price-amount").innerHTML = "";
```